# Xcode and objective c shenanigans

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

Baby new to Xcode, Cocoa touch and iOS development in general. And am taking the Stanford walkthrough for their iPhone class. I am a little confused at a couple of places and need to shoot my doubts to you guys:

I have two classes that I have created for my model, essentially CalculatorBrain.m and CalculatorBrain.h. 
From what I gather, in Objective C, creating a class essentially consists of two functions, one is to declare the class which contains the method/messages and other variables while the other is the actual implementation for the same. From this stems two questions:

1. Why must I declare a class without implementing it's methods at first? (the concept seems to be borrowed from interfaces) and only then move on to implementing it .
2. From the above question, as I go through the walkthrough, I notice that the class declaration took place in CalculatorBrain.h whereas the methods were actually implemented in CalculatorBrain.m. I am unable to grasp the nuances of why this was done so if anybody is willing to shed some light on this, it would really help

Thanks again,

Parijat Kalia!!!

Comment: In Objective C, you can think of each module as having an *interface* (.h file) and an *implementation* (.m file). This is very similar to other languages such as C, C++, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are traditions from the C world, and they're just common practice to avoid some problems. They aren't two classes, they are the definition (in the .h file) and the implementation (in the .c or .cc file).

If you defined the class in the .c file, you couldn't refer to it elsewhere because it wouldn't be defined. You could include your .c file, but then you'd have two copies of the code. You could also use the "extern" keyword, but at this point it's kind of odd.

If you put code in the .h file, then when it's included the code gets included. This means you can get compiler errors that you have three "getMyThing" functions.

This means you can give out your headers to others without giving away your top-secret implementation (useful for making libraries), include your header without worrying about the possible multiple definitions, etc. You can also add variables and functions in the .c file which people using the header (like your other code) can't see or use, so you don't have to worry about changing it later and having compilation break.

Comment: It's sort of an un-official interface. It serves the same purpose, but it's not a special kind of object like an interface in Java. The main reason to give your headers to someone else is to allow your code to be used as a library or to allow others to extend your code. The header contains all the details their compiler needs to make code that will link right, without tying them to an implementation. You'll find things like it's common to have 3 Linux Kernel packages in distros: headers, source, and binary. Drives/programs often need the headers but not the full source.